# Handling special characters when reading from Excel file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, streamwriter, oledbdataadapter

I'm developing a Windows Forms application in VS2013 Pro and in the app I am converting an XLSX file to a CSV file. The conversion code works great with one exception: certain special characters are either being omitted or causing the entire current cell's contents to be omitted (producing an empty string) - usually the latter happens.

Here's the code:

```
Private Shared Sub convertExcelToCsv(ByVal sourceFile As String, ByVal workSheetName As String, ByVal targetFile As String)
    Dim strConn As String = "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;data source=" & sourceFile & ";extended properties=""excel 12.0 xml;hdr=no"""
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim wrtr As StreamWriter = Nothing
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = Nothing
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = Nothing

    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection(strConn)
        conn.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from [" & workSheetName & "$]", conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        wrtr = New StreamWriter(targetfile)
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)

        For x As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim rowString As String = ""

            For y As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Get the current cell's contents, replace any pipe characters with a dash and remove any leading and trailing spaces
                Dim strCellText As String = dt.Rows(x)(y).ToString()
                Dim strCellTextCleaned As String = strCellText.Replace("|", "-").Trim

                rowString &= strCellTextCleaned & "|" ' System set up with pipe-delimited files
            Next y
            wrtr.WriteLine(rowString)
        Next x

        MessageBox.Show("Done! your " & sourceFile & " has been converted into " & targetFile & ".")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
        Try
            wrtr.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I look at the variable strCellText at run-time, I'm seeing cells that end with a space and then a hash mark (#) - **in the header cells only**, oddly enough, are being returned as an empty string - I've put a spaceh/hash mark in other cells and they come through fine.

I've tried other special characters in cells and I'm finding that these characters: !, %, & are causing the entire cell to be returned as an empty string - and only when the character is at the beginning or end of the cell contents and there's a space separating the character and the rest of the text.

So in a file I'm testing with column header "PROJECT #" becomes and empty string (as do two other header cells ending in a space/hash), but cell A2 ends in a space/hash but that comes through. So does a cell with just a hash mark.

Cells with "& 0", "% test" and "! 12345" all are being written to the csv as empty strings for that cell.

But if I put any of the above-mentioned characters anywhere **within** the cell contents, they come through.

I need to be able to allow for those characters - how can I do that?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Per Icepickle's suggestion I added "IMEX=1" to the end of the connection string - that solved one problem (no empty cells that have special characters), but caused another: While testing I put a percent sign in a field that had a date in the format M/D/YYYY. The percent is preceding the date. In the rest of that column - for every other date value - they all get set to a five-digit value. It's formatting the date column to a General format type field. The source file has that column formatted as a MM/DD/YYYY date format.

Suggestions?

Comment: You could try to add following extra parameter in your connection string: `"excel 12.0 xml;hdr=no;IMEX=1"`. This should force the loading as Text, and doesn't require the OleDbConnection to auto convert the values

Comment: @Icepickle - thanks, please see my updated post - one issue fixed, but caused a new problem... Also, what about the comment about not requiring OleDbConnection - what lines can I modify/remove?

Comment: No, you misunderstood the comment, the IMEX=1 makes sure everything is autoconverted to text, when IMEX=0 or omitted, then it scans the first x rows of your xlsx document to determine which kind of valueType is valid for the column, any that doesn't match that initially scanned valueType would be empty. As for the updated version, it heavily depends in which format you will receive the file, and if you are allowed to change the xlsx before converting it...